# Rails Bad Request Bad Uri Due to Curly Brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, webrick

I need my url to allow curly brackets. Like so

http://localhost:3000/?target={target_id}

The reason for this is that the {target_id} param will be replaced later by a third party site. I will not read that parameter I just need the site to load when the url looks this way.

currently I get this messege

Bad Request

Bad URI '?target={target_id}`

How do I get WeBrick to ignore the curly brackets in the url and display the site?

Comment: Can you CGI.escape it?

Comment: what do you mean? how would I do that

Comment: Depends on how you are building that url.  `root_url(target: '{target_id'})` should do it for you.  Otherwise `CGI.escape('{target_id}')` will do it.

Comment: I'm not building that url. That's a url someone would put into the address bar to get to my site